# azure log analytics use average and count in a query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am fairly new to azure log analytics, and I cant figure out how to run the average on a count of a string field.
I want to get the average "read" operations on a specific collection is cosmos.
I have tried the following:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and requestResourceType_s == "Collection" 
| summarize avg(count(OperationName)) by OperationName
```

According to the docs avg can only be used on integer values. I tried the project as well but that did not seem to work. Any ideas on how to get the average read operations?

Thanks,
Sasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to query below:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and requestResourceType_s == "Collection" 
| summarize mycount=count(OperationName) by OperationName
| summarize avg(mycount) by OperationName
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, much appreciated